# React component don't show in IE 11

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a react directive and i call it with that

```
<react-component name="StartAll" props="ctrl.props"> </react-component>
```

In Chrome,Firefox and Opera everything is fine but in IE 11 the react component just don't show .No error in console nothing ..

Comment: Is the component really wrapping "nothing"? If so, why isnt it a self closing component `react-component name="StartAll" props="ctrl.props" />` ? Can you make sure that it is a JS / React problem and not i.e. a CSS interpretation difference in IE11?

Comment: Yes i am sure that it is a JS/React problem cuz i have other thing in the page with the same class like in react directive and they show like it is .

Answer (score -1):

Use react-app-polyfill and put IE 11 FIRST in the list , it will not work if you
add it as last entry; I admit some ignorance as to why...

"development": [
      "ie 11", < == must be first entry in list ; will not work if last!!!!
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"

```
]
```

Comment: this is the BROWERLIST in JSON.Config